# Flask redirect using url_for with parameter

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm trying redirect the function to herself, but changing the value of a parameter.

This is my code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index(save=False):
    form = FormFields()
    if form.validate_on_submit:
        csv = Csv(form)
        csv.savecsv()
        return redirect(url_for('index', save=True))
    else:
        print(form.errors)
    return render_template('form.html', form=form, save=save)
```

I would like that when redirecting, the **save** variable would be True, but it is always False.

In the form code I have this:

```
{% if save %}
    <script type="text/javascript"> alert("Saved!");</script>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution

I changed it:

```
return redirect(url_for('index', save=True))
```

for this one

```
return render_template('form.html', form=form, save=True)
```

It will make a new render

and I added this in the form.html code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').val("");
});
```

this solves my problem, and the reason is that I have a confirmation message (when save is True) and the fields are cleared

but if someone really needs a `return redirect url_for`
can use Suman Niroula's solution without problems

Answer (score 0):

Use the default values in route:

```py
    @app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"], defaults={'save': False})
    @app.route('/<save>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def index(save):
        form = FormFields()
        if form.validate_on_submit:
            csv = Csv(form)
            csv.savecsv()
            return redirect(url_for('index', save=True))
        else:
            print(form.errors)
        return render_template('form.html', form=form, save=save)
```

Comment: returned this error: werkzeug.routing.BuildError
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'index' with values ['save'].

Comment: Works only on first request, in the second I receved this error: Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Comment: is there any way that the value doesn't stay in the URL or be sent as POST?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Comment: so whenever I redirect the value will it be explicit? I just need a confirmation message that a file has been saved and the forms cleaned.